# Storing date difference as Numeric value and extract Days,Hours,Minutes from that numeric value

Tags: postgresql

Have a table with 2 different days, Start Date and End date.
A person can check in and checkout multiple times in a month. My requirement is to calculate time difference between those 2 days and store in different table as number and display in UI as DAYS:HOURS:MIN

| Person | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PRS | 10-1-2022 1:43 | 10-1-2022 3:40 |
| PRS | 10-3-2022 10:11 | 10-5-2022 12:00 |
| PRS | 10-11-2022 3:00 | 10-12-2022 7:00 |

There are thousands of persons with difference dates. My requirement is Calculate the time difference for each row sum up and store it in different table as any type and provide total sum in number of days:Hours:Min.

I tried to convert those numbers as interval but when I try to add all different intervals the results are off.

Comment: Postgres has a built-in [date/time interval type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) - and [range types too](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) - which arguably is better than using some purely _numeric_ representation (internally, the interval and range types are still numeric, just as the `datetime`  type is too) so there's no performance hit. Why do you think a numeric type is the best approach here?

Comment: Also, please don't use `MM-d-yyyy` (or is it `dd-M-yyyy`? (see the problem?)) as a date/time format: it's very, very ambiguous and not lexicographically sortable. ISO 8601 and RFC 3339 exist for a reason, please use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `justify_interval` from here [Date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

```
select justify_interval(('10-1-2022 3:40'::timestamp - '10-1-2022 1:43'::timestamp) 
 + '10-5-2022 12:00'::timestamp - '10-3-2022 10:11'::timestamp );

 justify_interval 
------------------
 2 days 03:46:00
```

Comment: This partially solved my problem. I was able to store the values in milli seconds and extract them as interval and using justify_interval it gave me correct value in days hours and minutes. Thanks Adrian

Comment: Why store as millisecond(epoch I presume). Why not just do `extract(epoch from <timestamp_val>)`?

Comment: That's a limitation we have Adrain . Database is not ours  we use it as rest service and they designed that way  Totally agree that need to store in time stamp .

Comment: Your question shows start and end as timestamps. If that is not the case you should change that information.

Comment: We have that start and end time in our local database. And we need to calculate the time difference in epoch and send it to a service and they store that time in epoch and UI displays in Days:Hours:Min.  My problem is solved for now. Thanks